# shell script to exit out of the script if diskspace is more than 75

Tags: awk

I want a script to exit out of the script if disk space is beyond threshold(ex:75%). Trying below things, But no luck.

```
df -kh | awk '{if( 0+$5 >= 75 ) exit;}'
```

Trying above command, its not working. Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your `df` output is NOT coming in a single line or so, to make this you need to add `-P` option with it try following once.

```
df -hP  | awk '{if( 0+$5 >= 75 ){print "exiting now..";exit 1}}'
```

***OR***

```
df -hP | awk '$5+0>=75{print "exiting now..";exit 1}'
```

OR with mount name who is the culprit for breaching threshold.

```
df -hP | awk '$5+0>=75{print "Mount " $1 " has crossed threshold so exiting now..";exit 1}'
```

In case you don't have `-P` option in your box then try following.

```
df -k | awk '/^ +/ && $4+0>=75{print "Mount " prev"  has crossed threshold so exiting now..";exit 1} !/^ +/{prev=$0}'
```

I am using `print` statement to make sure `exit` is working. also `-P` option was tested on BASH systems.

Since OP told he needs to exit from complete script itself so requesting OP to add following code outside of `for` loop of his code.(I haven't tested it though but this should work)

```
if [[ $? -eq 1 ]]
then
    echo "Exiting the complete script now..."
    exit
else
    echo "Looks good so going further in script now.."
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I am not able to exit out of the script, its just exiting from that particular loop(for loop I am using). My concern is I have to exit out of the script without continuing with the further loops.

Comment: @Himavanth, use `exit 1` in my above code's `awk` commands. Then outside of your `for` loop from which it is coming out put a condition like `if [[ $? -eq 1 ]]; then echo "Exiting the complete script now..."; exit; else echo "Looks good so going further in script now.."; fi` I will post this to my code now too, let me know how it goes then?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this in a script to exit the script (as opposed to exiting a long awk script) then you need to call exit from the outer script:

```
if df -kh | awk  '{if ($5+0 > 75) exit 1 }'; then echo OK; else echo NOT; fi
```

Don't forget that df returns one line per mount point, you can do:

```
if dk -kh /home ....
```

to check for a particular mount point.